# Click a button and pop up a table

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a button in the asp.net web page, I want to display a table by clicking the button. Here are the images.

[image: image1]

And clicking "Search Equipment".

[image: image2]

I borrowed the code from somewhere. Originally it was jquery code and the button is a div section.
My questions:

1. If pure asp.net code, how to genereate this dynamic table? I know DataGrid is a choice, is there any other way? I don't want to display it until clicking the button.
2. Combination of asp.net and jquery. The button is an asp.net button but the table is got from client side skills.

Thanks.

Comment: Without any code, you're basically asking for a tutorial; this is not a tutorial website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle it all with server side code. It's much easier to handle, and there's no real reason to create a table with client side javascript.

1. Use a GridView and bind your datasource to it.
2. Use an UpdatePanel surrounding the search field and results to avoid refreshing the page.

Comment: I agree with you that it is much easier to handle, but "there's no real reason to create a table with client side javascript" and "use an UpdatePanel to avoid refreshing the page"? I don't think I agree much with that. Remember what an UpdatePanel does to your pages. I rather create a couple of javascript functions than add an update panel to my page for just this simple effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in pure asp.net code but it will require a post back when the button is pressed.

you can also use a `asp:gridview` control. It looks a lot like a table. and your code behind for the button would look something like this

```
Protected Sub okButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles okButton.Click
    ... //set your gridview up
    gridview1.datasource = whateveryourdatasourceis //can be list, array, datatable
    gridview1.databind()
    gridview1.visible = true
End Sub
```

the code above is vb.net

Hope this helps.